# What is the risk when editing crontab file without the "crontab -e" command?

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I developed a script in which I add lines to the crontab file with `echo` command and I remove lines with `sed` command.

I do not know the risk of that especially when I read on some web site that we have to edit crontab file with:

```
crontab -e
```

1. What is the risk of not using `crontab -e`?
2. Are there a risk that my edit will not taken account in the cron
   schedule?
3. Should I restart cron with `/etc/init.d/cron` restart?

Answer (score 1):

1. Syntax or other errors may not be detected.
2. Yes. Different cron implementations have different ways of detecting crontab changes. For example, Vixie cron relies on its `crontab` command to update the modification time of the spool directory to signal a change. You would have to know how your cron implementation works.
3. It's best to restart cron if you're not sure exactly how your cron works.

Bottom line: You should use `crontab` if possible. It's there for a reason. Your `crontab` command may have an option to take an existing crontab as an argument and install it to the system-wide crontab directory, so you could make whatever edits you need to using `sed` and then use `crontab` to install your changes.

Answer (score 0):

1. - Crontab would fail from the point where there is syntax error (linux)
   - Crontab would fail if there is an accidental new line is added (solaris)
2. You don't need to restart cron.